# Android fullscreen layout with additional layouts underneath, which are scrollable

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview

I have a layout displaying some images and text, with buttons at the bottom.

When a button is pressed, I need to display some new information below the buttons.

So the initial content needs to remain at the same height (height of the device screen), and the new content needs to be added beneath it, allowing the user to scroll down.

When a button is pressed it will ideally need to show the new content like a page anchor, but the part I'm having difficulty is getting the initial content to be fullscreened, and maintain that size when new content is added whilst also making the whole thing scroll-able.

I have been playing with different layouts, different height parameters, android:fillViewport="true" or not etc.

I can provide some XML / further explanation if necessary. But I'm not sure whether what I am aiming to achieve is possible or not. At least I'd like to get a scrollable overall view, with the top layout as fullscreen and some layouts underneath which the user can scroll to.

image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Make ScrollView container and add your layout #1 into it
2. Set height of layout #1 into the code according per screen height
3. After button click add layout #2 into ScrollView

UPDATED:
Ok, I can suggest you only this solution (it worked for me in emulator).
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff0000">

            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:onClick="btnClick"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void btnClick(View v){
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);

        RelativeLayout layout2 = new RelativeLayout(this);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300);
        layout2.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        layout1.getLayoutParams().height = scroll.getHeight();
        scroll.setFillViewport(false);
        container.addView(layout2, params);
    }

}
```

Comment: But the height of layout #1 has to be somewhat dynamic. In the sense that it needs to be just be fullscreen on any device. If it's fill_parent then I need to have a fillViewPort on the scrollview (which doesn't seem to expand with new layouts added).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. The key part I was missing I think was changing the viewport and possibly a few relative/linear layouts mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom `ScrollView` which sets the height of its first child to be its own height. This will simulate a fullscreen view while still being able to add content below it.

To handle screen size changes properly, the best is to override `onSizeChanged()` :

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        View view = getChildAt(0);
        if (view != null)
            view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, h)));
    }
}
```